# Should we apturl whenever possible?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answer-format, faq-suggestion, apturl

It seems that apt: doesn't work here,but there is a proxy for these type of sites

just provide apt.ubuntu.com/p/package_name

Should we use it(easy,fast and user friendly) or the traditional software center,apt-get or synaptic?

---

Example:

http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/vlc

*Note: doesn't work in Chrome on Ubuntu.*

DoctorMO has made another proxy

http://doctormo.org/2010/07/02/apturl-proxy/

Comment: I've opened a bug on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apturl/+bug/614590

Comment: I've asked the Ubuntu webmaster to look at that bug for us so we can get rolling on this.

Comment: Seems what it was apt.ubuntu.com/p/packageName now is https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/packageName.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The AptUrl demi-standard is a fantastic idea, and it promotes one of Ubuntu's (and Debian's) best features: awesome package installation and removal. They're also more usable than `sudo apt-get install ...` strings.

I say we promote the standard as much as possible. If we have to request an apt.ubuntu.com, so be it.

Comment: +1: For new users the default browser will pick up on the apt-url fine. For anybody else who uses a different browser, chances are they know apt well enough to succeed.

Answer (score 6):

I think once the apt.ubuntu.com bug is sorted that we should do it this way to cover our bases:

For desktop related questions:

- You should install [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org) ([install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/inkscape)), it's a great piece of software!

This links the user to the upstream project, where they can learn more about how to use it, etc, and also gives them an install link.

For server-related things we should do:

- openldap is great, install it via `sudo apt-get install openldap-server`

Complete answers will of course have both, but the apt.ubuntu.com way is clearly so much easier to use for desktop applications and we should encourage people to use it.

Comment: I've started using a format I copied from someone else that shows the package name (with link to launchpad) and the software centre icon (with apt link): `[compizconfig-settings-manager](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compizconfig-settings-manager) [![Install compizconfig-settings-manager](http://bit.ly/software-small)](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)`

Answer (score 2):

Apturl doesn't work on all browsers and desktop environments, so i think it is a safe bet to add the url and manual instructions. Or one could persuade someone maintaining apt.ubuntu.com to add generic instructions if it detects a browser that isn't supported.

Comment: Only on those environments that don't follow FreeDesktop.org spec.As for browsers it just requests an external protocol request which should work on all browsers.

Comment: the example site, apt.ubuntu.com shows me that i'm not running ubuntu (using chromium), sure apt://packagename should work but apt.ubuntu.com site at least doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I've added the feature request tag - I imagine this is a fairly easy change to make for this site. I believe it will be easier if someone starts by making a greasemonkey script that will support it, but quite a few sites have customisations for this or that.